# User always appear to be online?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm regularly updating last activity of the each user on certain actions in order to be able to get online users later. However when I run the query below, it always get me a result as if the user was online :

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE last_activity + INTERVAL 30 SECOND > NOW() and for_whom = '1461' and is_deleted=0
```

I tried to change the last_activity column value to a lower time, but the row is always returned. ?

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS you're using - this is highly RDBMS-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you're updating the last activity with MySQL's `NOW()`, not an explicit datetime from another source.

Also, your query will be much faster if you create an index on `info (for_whom, is_deleted, last_activity)` and rewrite the query a little:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    info
WHERE   for_whom = 1461
        AND is_deleted = 0
        AND last_activity > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 SECOND
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I was setting time through php which was on different web server. btw how can I create an index on info (for_whom, is_deleted, last_activity) and what does that mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Web server and DB server have the same system time.

Try `SELECT NOW()` to check DB server time.

Answer (score 0):

You should check **UTC part** of your `last_activity` datetime. It's probable you'll find surprise there. 
And other measures described here, may help (e.g. datetime syncrinization)